# Undefined variable on call blade view

Tags: laravel

I have a controller and a Bootstrap modal, when I call the variable in the function **RoomCheck** in my controller:

```
$availableRoomTypes
```

In the blade view, this error is displayed:

> Undefined variable: availableRoomTypes (View: /var/www/html/viure/Modules/Comprof/Resources/views/public/room-check-modal.blade.php)**

This is my **RoomCheck** function from my controller:

```
 public function RoomCheck($start, $end)
        {
            if (!$request->wantsJson()) {

                return $request;
            }
            $this->validate($request, [
                'checkIn' => 'required',
                'checkOut' => 'required',
            ]);

            $start = Carbon::parse($request->checkIn);
            $end = Carbon::parse($request->checkOut);

            $start_at = $start->format('Y-m-d');
            $end_at = $end->subDays(1)->format('Y-m-d');

            $roomsTypes = RoomType::all(); 

             $availableRoomTypes  = $roomsTypes->map(function ($type) use ($start, $end) {
                $unavailabilities = Unavailability::whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])
                ->where('room_type_id', $type->id)->get();
                $group = $unavailabilities->groupBy(function ($item) {
                    return $item->room_type_id . '_' . $item->reservation_id;
                });

                $totalReservation = $group->map(function ($query) {
                    return $query->first();
                });

                $type->availableroom = $type->room_count - $totalReservation->sum('quantity');

                return $type;
            });

            return response()->json([
                'date' => $request->checkIn,
                'availableRoomTypes' => $availableRoomTypes,
            ]);
        }
```

This is my modal blade view:

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Room Type
            @foreach($roomTypes as $roomType)
            <option value="{{ $roomType->id }}" @if (old('room_type_id') == $roomType->id) selected @endif>
              {{ $roomType->name }}
            </option>
          @endforeach
          </th>
            <th width="130">Available Room</th>
            @foreach($availableRoomTypes as $availableRoomTypess)
            <option value="{{ $availableRoomTypes }}" @if (old('availableRoomTypes') == $availableRoomTypes) selected @endif>
              {{ $availableRoomTypes }}
            </option>
          @endforeach
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

But when I call **$roomTypes** from the Store function in the same controller there is no error, but when I calling the **$availableRoomTypes** I get the error like above. What is wrong?

The action form is in the **roombook.blade.php** file, my capital bootstrap includes in the roombook file with the action form to the route store

What is my wrong? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: How you call `RoomCheck()` action??!

Comment: Give as some code of How you call the RoomCheck() ?

Comment: Your function returns a json response, where are your returning the view? You need to share the variable with the view.

Answer (score 2):

Your controller typically will return the variable in when calling the view, such as:

```
return view('roombook', ['date' => $request->checkIn,
            'availableRoomTypes' => $availableRoomTypes,]);
```